# HL-1110 XML Paper Brother printer does not install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing

Have tried installing on Windows and the printer works.

It is supposedly Linux compatible. Has anyone else found a printer driver for this printer?

I have tried through the console and got a supposed match with HL1070 which will not print, and via terminal and sudo with instructions from the Brother site but no package has turned up.

Comment: Could you provide a reference where you found information that the printer is Linux compatible? -- WHat exactly happens when you configure it as a HL 1070?

Answer (score 0):

Mine works well on ubuntu 14.04. I donwload the driver from Brother' site. Is a bash script than ask for the model of the printer and then install some packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you can bear with me I'll tell you how. It's long winded but not difficult.

1. From the Brother site get hl1110lpr.deb and hl1110cupswrapper.deb and install them.
2. Using the Muon package manager (synaptic won't find all the Brother files you need) install the following by typing "brother" in the search bar

brother-lpr-drivers-common
brother-lpr-drivers-laser
brother-cupswrapper-common
brother-cupswrapper-laser1
printer-driver-brlaser

The two files from the Brother site did not work on their own. It is possible that you don't need all of the other files but I've never bothered to find out as it made my printer work. Allthe best. Hope this helps.